# How to #include hash with ext, tr1, or __gnu_cxx in XCode, C++

Tags: c++, xcode, hash, dictionary

I'm trying to work with the [google-sparsehash library](http://google-sparsehash.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/sparse_hash_map.html) and I'd like to include the hash library described in the link,

```
using ext::hash;  // or __gnu_cxx::hash, or maybe tr1::hash, depending on your OS
```

and I've tried one of each:

```
#include <ext/hash>
#include <ext>
#include <__gnu_cxx>
#include <tr1>
```

which none worked with XCode. I've also "using", where I was told that __gnu_cxx does not contain "hash".   How do I describe this library to XCode (3.2.6) on OS X (10.6.8)?

Or more generally,  where is this hash function described in a Mac / XCode?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but isn't XCode and iOS for Objective C? The google hash map seems to be related to STL which is part of C++

Comment: @AJG85: XCode supports C and C++ as well.  And development for MacOS in addition to iOS

Comment: @Managu Ah thanks, I haven't seen a Apple product in years so I wasn't sure.

Comment: Yes it definitely supports C & C++,  I do my C++ dev on Apple machines with XCode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++11:

```
#include <functional>
using std::hash;
```

In C++03 with TR1:

```
#include <tr1/functional>
using std::tr1::hash;
```

Comment: Does `<tr1/functional>` really define `std::tr1::hash`?  I suspected so, but couldn't find any documentation to confirm.

Comment: @Managu: I can't confirm it without spending money on an obsolete document; but it's certainly there in the GNU implementation, and it certainly ended up in `<functional>` in C++11. All the standard function objects are defined in `<functional>`.

Answer (score 0):

So far as I can tell, it doesn't seem possible to get at the hash functors without also pulling in definitions for the various hash tables.  At least not without fooling around with library internal headers.

Try:

```
#include <ext/hash_map>
using __gnu_cxx::hash;
```

or:

```
#include <tr1/unordered_map>
using std::tr1::hash;
```