# c++: stl hash compilation issues

Tags: c++, macos, stl, compiler-errors, g++

The following example will not compile for me:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  std::string str = "Meet the new boss...";
  std::hash<std::string> hash_fn;
  size_t str_hash = hash_fn(str);

  std::cout << str_hash << '\n';
}
```

I get the following output from g++

```
> g++ -o test test.cpp 
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:8: error: ‘hash’ is not a member of ‘std’
test.cpp:8: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
test.cpp:8: error: ‘hash_fn’ was not declared in this scope
```

Am I missing a compile flag or something?

Related info:

```
> g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
Target: i686-apple-darwin10
Configured with: /var/tmp/gcc/gcc-5666.3~6/src/configure --disable-checking --enable-werror --prefix=/usr --mandir=/share/man --enable-languages=c,objc,c++,obj-c++ --program-transform-name=/^[cg][^.-]*$/s/$/-4.2/ --with-slibdir=/usr/lib --build=i686-apple-darwin10 --program-prefix=i686-apple-darwin10- --host=x86_64-apple-darwin10 --target=i686-apple-darwin10 --with-gxx-include-dir=/include/c++/4.2.1
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)

> uname -a
Darwin ############# 10.8.0 Darwin Kernel Version 10.8.0: Tue Jun  7 16:33:36 PDT 2011; ro
```

Comment: Try with the `-std=c++0x` flag, I think `std::hash` is part of C++11 isn't it?

Comment: nope, `cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=c++0x"`

Comment: I think I got it (see below) seems to be a namespace issue specific to macs, thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9005256/how-to-include-hash-with-ext-tr1-or-gnu-cxx-in-xcode-c)

this code compiles:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tr1/functional>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  double d = 3;
  std::tr1::hash<double> hash_fn;
  size_t str_hash = hash_fn(d);

  std::cout << str_hash << '\n';
}
```

Comment: If you use macports, you can install gcc 4.6 on your mac.